# How to generate and label multiple histograms as Query operator(s)?

Tags: dataset

The Dataset [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) doesn't indicate how to label a Histogram with the key.

```
titanic = 
  ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}][All, {"survived" ->(# /. {True -> 1, False -> 0} &)}]
```

[image]

```
titanic[Histogram, #] & /@ {"age", "survived"}
```

gives:

[image]

(Note, unlike functions such as Counts, which can operate on tuples of keys (ie, counts the products), it doesn't seem possible to use the syntax: `titanic[Histogram, {"age", "survived"}]`).

How can a Key be passed programmatically as argument to Histogram (or other operators) in order to label it, eg "age", "survived" ?

Of course it's possible to project individual columns with KeyTake and then histogram but that's not the same as operating on the data.

Comment: Perhaps `titanic[Composition[Histogram[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &,
  Pivot[#, 2] &
  ], {"age"}]`. (but `Pivot` is probably going away soon)

Comment: @Rojo, Pivot isn't documented and its definition is unreadably full of macros & `PackagePrivate parts. Where did you read about it?

Comment: It used to be documented before the final release. And it will go away, but I am hoping as it goes away, some other function will take its job because I find it pretty useful

Comment: Do you mean something like `titanic[Histogram[#[[All, 1]], PlotLabel -> First@Keys@#[[1]]] &, {#}] & /@ {"age", "survived"}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to modify what you already tried by very much.

```
Column[
  With[{key = #}, 
    titanic[Histogram[#, PlotLabel -> key] &, key]] & /@ {"age", "survived"}]
```

[image: histograms]

#### Edit

The comment by the OP is not clear to me. I offer up the following as my best interpretation of what he is asking for. I hope I'm not being obtuse.

```
Column[
  With[{val = #[[1]], lbl = #[[2]]}, 
      titanic[Select[#survived == val &]]
        [Histogram[#, {0, 80, 5}, PlotLabel -> lbl]&, "age"]]& 
    /@ 
      {{1, "Survivors by Age"}, {0, "Non-survivors by Age"}}]
```

[image: more-histograms]

Comment: +1, yet this method also is not a pure operator, since it partly straddles Dataset.

Comment: can you redefine this method as a Query operator?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I don't misunderstand the question.  It's not fancy or clever but basic programming still works:

```
f[x_] := Labeled[Histogram @ #, x] &;

titanic[f[#], #] & /@ {"age", "survived"}
```

[image]

The same thing as a `Table`:

```
Table[
  titanic[Histogram[#] ~Labeled~ x &, x],
  {x, {"age", "survived"}}
]
```

Comment: @m_goldberg Weird!  There are no quote marks on screen but they appear when I export (**Save Selection As...**) to PNG.  I didn't even notice that before.

Comment: Is it not possible to redefine your solution inline?

Comment: @alancalvitti What do you mean by "inline" in this case? Would you prefer `titanic[(x \[Function] Labeled[Histogram@#, x] &)[#], #] & /@ {"age", "survived"}` ?

Comment: by inline I mean as Query operators.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Histogram[titanic[[All, #]], ChartLabels -> Placed[#, Above], 
    ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {"age", "survived"} // Row
```

Gives this

[image]

Comment: titanic[[All,#]] is a projection like I mention in the last paragraph of my Q, it's not an operator applied to Dataset.